How to use ffmpeg or exiftool to write tags into meta data of mp4 file?
I have the following command executed under Ubuntu App on Windows 11:
ffmpeg -i "$mp4_file" \
    -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng \
    -metadata title="My Title Is Here Guys!" \
    -metadata subtitle="My Subtitle" \
    -metadata rating="4" \
    -metadata comment="My Comment Is Here!" \
    -metadata tags="my; tags; are; here;" \
    -codec copy "$meta_file"

And I have also tried:
exiftool -Title="$title" \
    -Subtitle="Does not work TODO" \
    -Keywords="my;tags;here;TODO" \
    -Comment="$summary" \
    "$mp4_file"

But only the Title and Comments is filled out in the metadata when I check the MP4 file's properties with Right Click > Properties > Details. The Subtitle and Tags are not written. What am I doing wrong? I also tried -metadata keywords instead of -metadata tags.


The problem is that Windows Properties doesn't read standard video tags (see exiftool's Quicktime tags page) for these properties.  Instead, it only reads the Microsoft specific tags.
Using exiftool, you could write the "Subtitle" and "Tags" properties with this command:
exiftool -Microsoft:Subtitle="Subtitle goes here" -Microsoft:Category="Tags go here" /path/to/files/
This command creates backup files.  Add -overwrite_original to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add -r to recurse into subdirectories.
I do not know if ffmpeg has the ability to write the Microsoft tags.
You can find a list of what metadata Windows reads to fill out the Properties⇾Details window in this exiftool post.

Awesome you are a life saver! I'm currently doing it this way now exiftool -Title="$title"      -Subtitle="$subtitle"     -Keywords="$tags"      -Comment="$summary"      -Microsoft:Subtitle="$subtitle"      -Microsoft:Category="$tags_semicolon_separated"      "$mp4_file"
